# 'CompiledFFI' instead of 'FFI' when including 'cairocffi'

Tags: python, cairo, python-cffi

I want to use Pango with the Cairo backend in Python 3. I chose 'cairocffi' for reasons that are not relevant here. I am trying to run [the example in the documentation](http://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cffi_api.html#example-using-pango-through-cffi-with-cairocffi). It calls Pango through CFFI. The very beginning of the example

```
import cairocffi
import cffi
ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.include(cairocffi.ffi)
```

gives the following error.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 494, in include
    type(ffi_to_include).__name__,))
TypeError: ffi.include() expects an argument that is also of type cffi.FFI, not 'CompiledFFI'
```

I have been trying to understand the CFFI documentation, but I am completely lost. First, where is `CompiledFFI` documented? Second, why do not I see `include`, `cdef`, `set_source` methods in [the `FFI` interface](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref.html#ffi-interface)? And the main question is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cairocffi was updated to use the more modern way of using cffi, but this makes the example outdated.  You should ask the cairocffi authors to update the example.

`ffi.include()` is documented here: http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffi-ffibuilder-include-combining-multiple-cffi-interfaces.  The confusion comes from the fact that in the modern equivalent, the `ffi` object would be called `ffibuilder` instead in that example (which would be structured differently).

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that 'CompiledFFI' is not even mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Right.  The two types 'FFI' and 'CompiledFFI' are generally very similar, but I wrote a note in the docs (http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref.html#ffi-interface).

Comment: Sorry, I can't find 'CompiledFFI' on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.

Comment: Would you like to help me in writing a working example? 'ffibuilder.include(cairocffi.ffi)' says that 'cairocffi.ffi' should be of type 'cffi.FFI'. If I give the C definition of Cairo context 'cairo_t' to 'ffibuilder.cdef' instead, compile 'ffibuilder', and use it in an example, a 'pangocairo' function complains that the type of Cairo context created with 'cairocffi' ('import cairocffi') does not fit.